# Extracting part of a cell's value from a list of files in a folder to a master?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to extract multiple pieces of data from every file in a folder and bring it into a table in a new document.

The source files are data collection runs and are identically formatted. The easier copy and paste parts are numerical data values (F6:H6 and F7:H7).

The non-numerical values are all the other lines. I only want a portion of them.
For example the data from A1 of the source file is the run title which is formatted: "Run ## - 'run description'", but I only want the run number.
If I copy and paste it it comes out like "RUN 25 - Power Eval." when all I want is "25".

I've tried a handful of things. I'm sure there might be an easy way to use Mid but I couldn't figure it out.
Each source file is analyzed using a macro so I also tried adding a named range named Runnum in each of the files that uses a function to extract the run number from the file name. The name range works, like if I put "=Runnum" in a cell of the source file it returns just the number i.e. "25", but I wasn't able to figure out how to call the value of the named range and extract it.

The other items that aren't easily copy and paste-able fall under the same issue. I should hopefully be able to apply the fix to the rest.

The values I am extracting the data from are all cells that contain formulas. This is why I was using PasteSpecial for the easy copy and paste lines, but I'm not sure if this will be a factor in the solution for the other lines.

```vb
Sub Summary()

    Dim xFd As FileDialog
    Dim xSPath As String
    Dim xXLSXFile As String       'file to process
    Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim rowTarget As Long         'output row
        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False  
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False 
    
    rowTarget = 8
    
    'reset application settings in event of error
    On Error GoTo errHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    'xWsheet = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Set xFd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xFd.Title = "Select a folder:"
    If xFd.Show = -1 Then
        xSPath = xFd.SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Right(xSPath, 1) <> "\" Then xSPath = xSPath + "\"
    
    'set up the target worksheet
    Set wsTarget = Sheets(1)
    
    'loop through the Excel files in the folder
    xXLSXFile = Dir(xSPath & "*.xlsx")
    Do While xXLSXFile <> ""
        If xXLSXFile <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
            Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(xSPath & xXLSXFile)
            Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets(1)
        
            ''With wsTarget
                ''.Range("A" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("Runnum").Value
            ''End With
                    
            With wsSource
                ''.Range("Runnum").Value = wsTarget.Range("A" & rowTarget).Value
                ''.Names("Runnum").RefersToRange.Value
                ''wsTarget.Range("B" & rowTarget).Value
                ''.Range("A1").Value = Mid(str, 5, InStr(str, " ") - 5).Copy
                ''wsTarget.Range("A" & rowTarget).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 
                ''.Range("Runnum").Copy
                ''wsTarget.Range("A" & rowTarget).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .Range("A1").Copy
                wsTarget.Range("A" & rowTarget).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues  'Run# 'remove first 4 characters and all characters after number/from the "-" -1
                .Range("B4").Copy
                wsTarget.Range("B" & rowTarget).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .Range("F6:H6").Copy
                wsTarget.Range("C" & rowTarget).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .Range("F7:H7").Copy
                wsTarget.Range("F" & rowTarget).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .Range("D1").Copy
                wsTarget.Range("I" & rowTarget).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues  'remove first 7 characters
                .Range("B9").Copy
                wsTarget.Range("J" & rowTarget).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .Range("B13").Copy
                wsTarget.Range("K" & rowTarget).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues  'remove every thing after the fist space -1
            End With
        End If
        
        'close the source workbook, increment the output row and get the next file
        wbSource.Close SaveChanges:=False
        rowTarget = rowTarget + 1
        xXLSXFile = Dir()
    Loop
    
errHandler:
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
       
    Set wsSource = Nothing
    Set wbSource = Nothing
    Set wsTarget = Nothing
End Sub
```

I turned a few of the lines of code in the loop into comments with a '' just to show a few of the things I've tried. Really I kept them in to help me debug.

Comment: You'll be on your way to writing legible code when you stop addressing cells as ranges. Cells are addressed by their coordinates, ranges by their names. Coordinates are numbers, names are strings. Yes, you can take numbers and concoct a string from them and Excel will dutifully convert that string back to numbers which it can use, but that roundtrip isn't efficient. It's cumbersome to write, especially when both rows and columns are variables, and its legibility is open to argument. `wsTarget.Range("B" & rowTarget)` defines `wsTarget.Cells(rowTarget, 2)` or `wsTarget.Cells(rowTarget, "B")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some suggestions for changes and the extractions you need:

```vba
Option Explicit

Sub Summary()

    Dim xFd As FileDialog
    Dim xSPath As String
    Dim xXLSXFile As String       'file to process
    Dim wbTarget as workbook, wsTarget As Worksheet, rwTarget As Range, v
    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim rowTarget As Long         'output row
        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    'reset application settings in event of error
    On Error GoTo errHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    xSPath = GetAFolder("Select a folder:") 'extract code to re-usable function
    If Len(xSPath) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    Set wbTarget = ActiveWorkbook  '## Target workbook
    Set wsTarget = wbTarget.Worksheets(1) 'set up the target worksheet
    Set rwTarget = wsTarget.Rows(8)
    
    xXLSXFile = Dir(xSPath & "*.xlsx") 'loop through the Excel files in the folder
    Do While xXLSXFile <> ""
    
        If xXLSXFile <> wbTarget.Name Then
            Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(xSPath & xXLSXFile)
            With wbSource.Worksheets(1)
                rwTarget.Columns("A").Value = RunNumber(.Range("A1").Value) 'call function
                rwTarget.Columns("B").Value = .Range("B4").Value
                rwTarget.Columns("C").Resize(1, 3).Value = .Range("F6:H6").Value
                rwTarget.Columns("F").Resize(1, 3).Value = .Range("F7:H7").Value
                v = .Range("D1").Value
                rwTarget.Columns("I").Value = Right(v, Len(v) - 7) 'remove first 7 chars from D1
                rwTarget.Columns("J").Value = .Range("B9").Value
                rwTarget.Columns("K").Value = Split(.Range("B13").Value, " ")(0) 'up to first space
            End With
        End If
        
        'close the source workbook, increment the output row and get the next file
        wbSource.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Set rwTarget = rwTarget.Offset(1, 0)
        xXLSXFile = Dir()
    Loop
    
errHandler:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    'typically there's no need to set objects to Nothing when you're done...
End Sub

'extract the run number
Function RunNumber(ByVal v)
    v = UCase(Trim(Split(v, "-")(0))) 'the part before the dash
    RunNumber = Trim(Replace(v, "RUN", ""))
End Function

'push this out into a re-usable function
Function GetAFolder(dlgTitle As String) As String
    Dim rv As String
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = dlgTitle
        If .Show = -1 Then
            rv = .SelectedItems(1)
            If Right(rv, 1) <> "\" Then rv = rv & "\"
        End If
    End With
    GetAFolder = rv
End Function
```

Comment: @ Tim Williams `ErrHandler` is a misleading name for the label here because no errors are handled. I usually name such labels as `ErrExit` or `SideExit`. A "Handler" would fix the problem and return to running the code.

Comment: @Variatus - maybe not perfect but understandable to mean "go here if there's an error", and just performs a minimal "handling" by re-enabling alerts before the method exits.  Not my choice of name though - just re-using the OP's code.

Comment: Feel free to remove or change variables. Again the errhandler was from another site's solution.

Comment: I have directly copy and pasted your code into a new module and after running it it seems to start working, but nothing gets pasted to the new document.

Comment: Have you tried debugging?   Kind of difficult for me to know exactly what the issue is...  Does it open any files for example?

Comment: Sorry, yeah I didn't give you much there.. I turned screen updating back on to see if I could see something, but nothing more then when it was off. The macro runs, it asks me to select a folder, then it deselects and reselects the open 'Master' summary workbook as if it was running through the loop for each of the files in the folder.
But then the macro completes and nothing gets 'pasted' to the master. and unfortunately with the loop, I am unable to step through it with F8..

Comment: Does it enter the `Dir()` loop?  If nthing seems to be happening then that might be a good place to start.

Comment: I guess I don't know. It takes a good 10 seconds to run after selecting the folder. It de/selects the master wb 5 times which is how many files I have in my test folder that I have been using.

Comment: But on the other hand it selects and deselects the master quickly as if there aren't any arguments it's running through once the next source file is opened. 
But after I turned off screen updating shouldn't I actually see each of the source files opening? I have a simple macro that converts all .CSV files in a folder to an .xlsx file and I can actually see each of the files open when the macro converts each one.

Comment: If you put breakpoints you can see where the code is reaching.  If screenupdating is not disabled then you should see if files are being opened.

Comment: That's a fun little trick I wish I would have know (and probably should have already know) a long time ago. Thanks. So I added a break point inside the loop. After running the macro and selecting the folder it opens up the first file, then stepping through the loop with F8 nothing happens. The file closes, and then goes back through the loop and opens the next file. 
Could it be because the cells it is extracting the data from have formulas in them? Actually never mind I just check and a copy and pasted values on A1 of the first source file when I was originally trying to write the code.

Comment: Formulas or not it should still pick up the values.

Comment: I do have this module in a PERSONAL.XLSB VBAProject not the actual VBAProject of the master. would that make a difference?
And the sheet names are the same as the file name, not just "sheet1", but I think that wouldn't matter because ".Worksheets(1)" takes care of that.

Comment: `ThisWorkbook` refers to the workbook where the code is running, so Yes it will make a difference - all the data will go to PERSONAL.XLSB...  You'll need to adjust the line `Set wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)`

Comment: Ok, yup that's it.  I unhid my personal and all the data was there. How do I change that line to put the data in the open file?

Comment: `Set wsTarget = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)` if that's the one you want.  See my edits above - also need an ajustment in the Dir() loop.

Comment: Oh duh.. I was seeing 'This'Workbook and was reading 'Active'Workbook which is why I didn't see what was wrong.. thank you

Comment: How do I replace `Set rwTarget = wsTarget.Rows(8)` with something like `Set rwTarget = wsTarget.Cells(wsTarget.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row`?

Comment: never mind, I think I just needed to remove the ".Row" at the end

Answer (score 1):

I like what you've started. After using copy/paste in one of my earliest macros, I now find that my macro breaks if I happen to need to use the clipboard when typing something while the macro is running. So I highly recommend avoiding the use of the clipboard in this situation.

Instead of copy/paste, you can consider using a variable, or even better, just assign the target cell as the value of the source cell. Example from your sample can change from

```
.Range("B4").Copy
wsTarget.Range("B" & rowTarget).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

To a single line:

```
wsTarget.Range("B" & rowTarget) = .Range("B4").Value
```

Thus, using the same concept, you can apply the changes you described for cells `A1`, `D1`, and `B13` using the same method but first modifying the result.

```
With .Range("A1")
     wsTarget.Range("A" & rowTarget) = Trim(Mid(.Value, InStr(1, .Value, " "), InStr(1, .Value, " ")))
End With

With .Range("D1")
    wsTarget.Range("I" & rowTarget) = Mid(.Value, 8, Len(.Value))
End With

With .Range("B13")
    wsTarget.Range("K" & rowTarget) = Left(.Value, InStr(1, .Value, " ") - 1)
End With
```

Comment: Thanks. Noted on the copy and paste tip.

Comment: I tried this is as well. Was I able to put all of these within the "With wsSource" statement?
When running it it was able to get all the way to opening the first file in the folder, but then it stops.

Comment: You should be able to. My own sample test used a `With` though I did not use a open file in my sample. Do you have it working now? If not, if you could share the latest version I can test it with the latest changes.